# How to Compare String in a Dataframe column with a sub-string in another Dataframe and extract the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have 2 dataframes:**
DF1

| ID | Name | Category---- |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Fruit |
| 2 | Orange | Fruit |
| 3 | brocolli | Vegetable |
| 4 | Spinach | Vegetable |

DF2

| UserID | Date | UserName | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01/01/2020 | AAA | Ordered 1 Box Apples |
| 111 | 01/02/2021 | AAA | Ordered 1KG spinach |
| 222 | 15/03/2021 | BBB | Ordered 3 boxes of Orange |

Can anyone help how I can match the "Description" from DF2 which contains "Name" string from DF1 and add the respective "Category" column in DF2?

Desired Output:

| UserID | Date | UserName | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01/01/2020 | AAA | Ordered 1 Box Apples | Fruit |
| 111 | 01/02/2021 | AAA | Ordered 1KG spinach | Vegetable |
| 222 | 15/03/2021 | BBB | Ordered 3 boxes of Orange | Fruit |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit - Second solution below as per OP comments**

**First** : This code uses **MERGE** to do the same task

```html
import pandas as pd

# Input Data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Apple','Orange','Brocolli','Spinach'], 'Category':['Fruit', 'Fruit','Vegitable','Vegitable']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01/01/2020','02/02/2021','03/03/2022'], 'Description':['Ordered 1 Box Apple', 'Ordered 1 KG spinach','Ordered 3 Box Orange']})

# Data Processing
pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on = df2['Description'].str.lower().str.split(' ', expand=True)[3], right_on = df1['Name'].str.lower(), how='left' ).drop('key_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

**Second Solution**

Updating code as per OP comments below

```html
 fruit_cat_mapping = { i[0]:i[1] for i in df1[['NAME','CATEGORY']].values}

def mapper_func(x):
  for key in fruit_cat_mapping.keys():
      if x.find(key.lower()) > -1:
         res = fruit_cat_mapping[key]
         return res

df2['Description'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: mapper_func(x))
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, works well. However the use case is a bit more complicated. where in dataframe 2 description is free text and may have anything in it. It may be a string with special characters and multiple fruit names in it. I was trying to use contains and apply.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek

`def matcher(x):   
 print(x)
    res = df1.loc[df1['NAME'].str.contains(x, regex=False, case=False), 'CATEGORY']
    return ','.join(res.astype(str))


df2['Category'] = df2['Description'].apply(matcher)
`
Problem in this solution is contains is checking if description is contained inside Name of df1, i am looking for a reversal of this one.

Comment: would you be able to help fix above contains snnipet?

Comment: Check edited code. Created an dictionary first with NAME & CATEGORY. Use that with APPLY & FIND inside a LAMBDA function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek.
`import pandas as pd


# Input Data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['AssessmentCompletedWOReason','Proceed to Assessment','TriageCompleted'], 'Category':['Assessed','Routed To Assessment','Triaged']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1234','3333','56564'], 'MESSAGE':['AssessmentCompletedWOReason AST Pays_ Ofr', 'TriageCompleted Proceed to Assessment Sufficient Triage_Ofr','AssignmentCompleted  Assessment Assessment']})

print(df1)
print(df2)`

Comment: `fruit_cat_mapping = { i[0]:i[1] for i in df1[['Name','Category']].values}
print(fruit_cat_mapping)


def mapper_func(x):
  return [fruit_cat_mapping[key]  for key in fruit_cat_mapping.keys() if x.find(key.lower()) > -1][0]


df2['Category'] = df2['MESSAGE'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: mapper_func(x))
print(df2)`

Comment: --------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6a5c904d4cb7> in <module>()
      7 
      8 
----> 9 df2['Category'] = df2['MESSAGE'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: mapper_func(x))
     10 print(df2)

Comment: This ''AssignmentCompleted  Assessment Assessment' was not available in the other column.

Comment: Hoping every row in df2 must have a representation in other column, Use this function if not so: def mapper_func(x):
   for key in fruit_cat_mapping.keys():
     if x.find(key.lower()) > -1:
        res = fruit_cat_mapping[key]
        return res

Comment: Added same in code

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It worked. You are a python guru! @Abhishek

Comment: Thanks, just learning like you everyday.

Comment: I have a table in database. Which has some free text fields like message. I am looking for a solution to dynamically map the columns of this table with a values and deriving new column.

Comment: Data Table:
|ID | Message | Team | Person|  Action|   ActionName  | Department|
|---- |  -------      |   -----  |   ------   |    ------  |    ----------    | ----------|
|111  | FWD document for approval|   Home  Loans|     Nam |       DocumentScan | Scanning | LoansApproval|
|222  | Manually Validated Doc   | ManualCheck| Tam  |  Manual Checking |  Validation | LoansApproval|
|333  |Loan Approved             | Approvals  | DAM  | Grant Approval | Approval | LoansApproval| 
|444  | FWD document for approval|   Personal  Loans|     Sam |       DocumentScan | Scanning | LoansApproval|

Comment: Mapping Table:
|Rule_Id | ColumnName | Lookup | Category |
|---------|-----------|--------|----------|
|1     | Message   | FWD document | HL Queue|
|1         |Team       | Home Loans   | HL queue|        
|2     | Message   | FWD document | PL Queue|
|2         |Team       | Personal Loans   | PL queue|        
|3         |Message       | Loan Approved   | Approved|

Comment: Mapping table is maintained by users and new mapping can be defined in this based on new entries in Data Table which need to be categorised. Structure of this table can be changed as this solution is not yet final.
Category is defined with the combination of one or more column values. Looking for a solution in python where in category is added in data table based on the rules defined in mapping table.
Can someone help me simplify this solution?

Comment: Output:
|ID |   Message| Team| Person|  Action|ActionName| Department| Category |
|--- |-----|----|-----|------ |-------| -------| -------- | 
|111  | FWD document for approval|   Home  Loans|     Nam |       DocumentScan | Scanning | LoansApproval| HL Queue |
|222  | Manually Validated Doc   | ManualCheck| Tam  |  Manual Checking |  Validation | LoansApproval|
|333  |Loan Approved             | Approvals  | DAM  | Grant Approval | Approval | LoansApproval|  Approved|
|444  | FWD document for approval|   Personal  Loans|     Sam |       DocumentScan | Scanning | LoansApproval| PL Queue |

Answer (score 2):

You can try `str.extract` then `map`

```
import re
c = '('+'|'.join(df1.Name.tolist())+')'

df2['new'] = df2.Description.str.extract(c,flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0].str.upper().\
                  map(dict(zip(df1.Name.str.upper(),df1.Category)))

0        Fruit
1    Vegetable
2        Fruit
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @BENY. Error encountered.

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: FutureWarning: currently extract(expand=None) means expand=False (return Index/Series/DataFrame) but in a future version of pandas this will be changed to expand=True (return DataFrame)
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1d38e6ad3392> in <module>()
      1 c = '('+'|'.join(df1.Name.tolist())+')'
      2 
----> 3 df2['new'] = df2.Description.str.extract(c,flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0].str.upper().map(dict(zip(df1.Name.str.upper(),df1.Category)))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`